# Why server can't read boolean from client when using socket in java?

Tags: java, sockets

I try to make caro game with 2 player online. I call "MrA" and "Mrb". In my program, when "Mra" invite "Mrb", "Mrb" can accept or reject. But when I try to send data from "Mrb" to server after "Mrb" get invitation from "Mra" an error occurred ("Mrb" can read from server but can not reply server). This is my code:

**Code:**

*Server:*

```
package controller;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import model.User;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int PORT = 4444;
        boolean stop = false;
        Executor pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
        ArrayList<User> listUsers = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            System.out.println("Server start at port " + PORT);
            while (!stop) {
                try {
                    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                    ClientHandler clientHandler = new ClientHandler(clientSocket, listUsers);
                    pool.execute(clientHandler);
                    System.out.println("Connect to server success!");

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Client Server can not connect to server! " + e);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Can not create Server Socket! " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

*ClientHandler:*

```
class ClientHandler implements Runnable {

    private Socket socket;
    private User userConnected;
    private volatile boolean stop;
    private ArrayList<User> listUsers;

    private DataOutputStream dataOutStream;
    private DataInputStream dataInStream;
    private ObjectOutputStream objOutStream;
    private ObjectInputStream objInStream;

    public ClientHandler() {
    }

    public ClientHandler(Socket socket, ArrayList<User> listUsers) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.listUsers = listUsers;
        this.userConnected = null;
        this.stop = false;

        try {
            dataOutStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            dataInStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            objOutStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            objInStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error when create in/output stream! " + e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!stop) {
            try {
                String code = dataInStream.readUTF();
                switch (code) {
                    case "login": {
                        loginUser();
                    }
                    break;

                    case "invite": {
                        boolean inviteSucess = inviteUser();
                        dataOutStream.writeBoolean(inviteSucess);
                        dataOutStream.flush();
                    }
                    break;

                }
                // display user login success
                for (User user : listUsers) {
                    System.out.println("User Name:" + user.getUserName());
                }
                System.out.println("+++++++++++++");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                    dataInStream.close();
                    dataOutStream.close();
                    objInStream.close();
                    objOutStream.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Can not close connection! " + ex);
                }
                stop = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void loginUser() {
        try {
            String userName = dataInStream.readUTF();
            userConnected = new User(userName, dataInStream, dataOutStream, objOutStream, objInStream);
            listUsers.add(userConnected);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    private boolean inviteUser() {
        boolean inviteSucces = false;
        try {
            String invitedName = dataInStream.readUTF();

            for (User user : listUsers) {
                if (user.getUserName().equals(invitedName)) {

                    
                    user.getDataOutputStream().writeUTF("invite");
                    user.getDataOutputStream().flush();
                    user.getDataOutputStream().writeUTF(userConnected.getUserName());
                    user.getDataOutputStream().flush();
                    System.out.println("send username success");
                    inviteSucces = user.getDataInputStream().readBoolean(); //error here. user.getDataInputStream() can not read boolean from client.
                    System.out.println(inviteSucces+ "read boolean from client success");
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return inviteSucces;
    }

}
```

*Client:*

```
package controller;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client implements Runnable {

    private Socket socket;
    private final int PORT = 4444;
    private final String HOST = "localhost";
    private volatile boolean stop;

    private DataOutputStream dataOutStream;
    private DataInputStream dataInStream;
    private ObjectOutputStream objOutStream;
    private ObjectInputStream objInStream;

    public Client() {
        try {
            this.socket = new Socket(HOST, PORT);
            this.stop = false;

            try {
                dataOutStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                dataInStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                objOutStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                objInStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                Thread t = new Thread(this);
                t.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error when create in/output stream! " + e);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Can not create client server! " + e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!stop) {
            try {
                String code = dataInStream.readUTF();
                switch (code) {
                    case "invite": {
                        String userInvite = dataInStream.readUTF();
                        System.out.println("Inviter name:"+userInvite);
                         System.out.println("Before send true to server");
                        dataOutStream.writeBoolean(true);
                         System.out.println("After send true to server");
                        dataOutStream.flush();
                    }
                    break;
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Can not read from dataInStream! " + e);
                try {
                    socket.close();
                    dataInStream.close();
                    dataOutStream.close();
                    objInStream.close();
                    objOutStream.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Can not close connection! " + ex);
                }
                stop = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public void login(String userName) {
        try {
            dataOutStream.writeUTF("login");
            dataOutStream.flush();
            dataOutStream.writeUTF(userName);
            dataOutStream.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    public boolean invite(String invitedName){
        boolean inviteSucess = false;
        try {
            dataOutStream.writeUTF("invite");
            dataOutStream.flush();
            dataOutStream.writeUTF(invitedName);
            dataOutStream.flush();
            inviteSucess = dataInStream.readBoolean();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return inviteSucess;
    }

    

}
```

**Output:**
*Server:*

```
Server start at port 4444
Connect to server success!
Connect to server success!
User Name:Mra
+++++++++++++
User Name:Mra
User Name:Mrb
+++++++++++++
send username success
```

*Mra client:*

```
User Name: Mra
Inviter name:Mrb
Before send true to server
After send true to server
```

*Mrb client:*

```
User Name: Mrb
```

UPDATE: User class:

note: I saved the socket at first. But it didn't work and I tried saving the streams.

```
package model;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class User {
    private String userName;
    private DataInputStream dataInputStream;
    private DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
    private ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream;
    private ObjectInputStream objectInputStream;

    public User() {
    }
    
    public User(String userName, DataInputStream dataInputStream, DataOutputStream dataOutputStream, ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream, ObjectInputStream objectInputStream) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.dataInputStream = dataInputStream;
        this.dataOutputStream = dataOutputStream;
        this.objectOutputStream = objectOutputStream;
        this.objectInputStream = objectInputStream;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    
    public DataInputStream getDataInputStream() {
        return dataInputStream;
    }

    public void setDataInputStream(DataInputStream dataInputStream) {
        this.dataInputStream = dataInputStream;
    }

    public DataOutputStream getDataOutputStream() {
        return dataOutputStream;
    }

    public void setDataOutputStream(DataOutputStream dataOutputStream) {
        this.dataOutputStream = dataOutputStream;
    }

    public ObjectOutputStream getObjectOutputStream() {
        return objectOutputStream;
    }

    public void setObjectOutputStream(ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream) {
        this.objectOutputStream = objectOutputStream;
    }

    public ObjectInputStream getObjectInputStream() {
        return objectInputStream;
    }

    public void setObjectInputStream(ObjectInputStream objectInputStream) {
        this.objectInputStream = objectInputStream;
    }
    
}
```

*Run Client*

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package view;

import controller.Client;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author hoang
 */
public class LoginForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form LoginForm
     */
    private Client client;
    public LoginForm() {
        initComponents();
        this.client = new Client();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("Invite");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("Login");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(158, 158, 158)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(84, 84, 84)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 111, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 72, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addGap(76, 76, 76))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(43, 43, 43)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton2))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 96, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(115, 115, 115))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String userName = jTextField1.getText();
        this.client.login(userName);
        System.out.println("User Name: "+userName);
    }                                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        if(this.client.invite("Mra")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Invite success to Mra");
        }
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LoginForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LoginForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LoginForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(LoginForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new LoginForm().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

This is how my program works : Mra and Mrb connect Server -> Server add Mra,Mrb and socket to ListUser -> Mra send "invite" + "Mrb" to Server -> Server search "Mrb" in ListUser and get Streams -> Server send "invite" +"Mra" to "Mrb". Then "Mrb" will accept and send `true` to Server. But Server can not read this respone!

Thanks all. Have a good day!

Comment: Please also give imports...

Comment: Also give User class to test. Please give us [mcve].

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I've edited

Comment: How do you launch clients?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I added it above. Sorry for this omission. Because I feel the code is too long and I want to omit some unimportant parts.

Comment: My error happened when I try to read data from a client by get DataInputStream from ArrayList I saved before